# Health check to detect redis master from google tcp load balancer

Tags: networking, load-balancing, tcp, google-compute-engine, redis

I am trying to setup a google TCP internal Load Balancer. Instance group behind this lb consists of redis-server processes listening on port 6379. Out of these redis instances, only one of them is master.

**Problem**: Add a TCP health check to detect the redis master and make lb divert all traffic to redis master only.

**Approach**: 
Added a TCP Health Check for the port 6379. 
In order to send the command `role` to redis-server process and parse the response, I am using the optional params provided in the health check. Please check the screenshot [here](http://prnt.sc/esojhn).

**Result**: Health check is failing for all. If I remove the optional request/response params, health check starts passing for all.

**Debugging**:

1. Connected to lb using netcat and issued the command `role`, it sends the response starting with `*3`(for master) and `*5`(for slave) as expected.
2. Logged into instance and stopped redis-server process. Started listening on port 6379 using `nc -l -p 6379` to check what exactly is being received at the instance's side in the health check. It does receive `role\r\n`.
3. After step 2, restarted redis-server and ran `MONITOR` command in redis-cli, to watch log of commands received by this process. Here there is no log of `role`.
   This means, instance is receiving the data(`role\r\n`) over tcp but is not received by the process redis-cli(as per `MONITOR` command) or something else is happening. Please help.

Comment: Are your Redis clients able to use [Redis Sentinels](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel)?  If so, you could load balance among *any* of a pool of Redis Sentinels; the client would thus ask the Sentinel for the currrent Redis master -- rather than having your load balancer do the Redis master discovery.

Comment: @Castaglia No. I have explored that approach and kept it as a secondary option. First, I am trying to make lb discover the redis master.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting an answer, it will certainly benefit the community.